# How can I debug the library using .pdb file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin.forms, pdb-files

I have been looking through ways to **debug external projects like BaseLibrary **. So I haven't seen such a code structure or worked on it. I think I can debug those projects with the use of the **.pdb file** present in the output.

[image]

This is how the project structure looks like. And I will be debugging the last project which is being highlighted. I have gone through these links

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/sourcelink?pivots=windows

I have added references for pdb file. I'm not sure if it is incorrect format the reference of pdb file is C:\Workspace\Xamarin.IntegrationLibrary\Output\netstandard2.1  as you can see in the following image.

[image]

But they are not helping me with my requirement because it is talking about debugging the NuGet packages which I'm installing in my current project. I want to debug the **external projects**. Currently, I'm able to navigate to assembly of the base library but I'm not able to navigate to source code or methods. As you can see in the following image.

[image]

I even tried debugging in dnSpy but I'm not able to give the executable for that. Also, it is not exactly what I require because I have to debug within the project using pdb.

[image]
Some solution says double-clicking on the DLL in the module opens the source code. Well I tried that as well as you can see the following screenshot

[image]
I am able to **load the .pdb symbols** but **I want to navigate and debug** the **source code of base library** and integration library from **xamarin.xyzApp project**. I have no clue how to proceed with this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could check the location of the external code's .pdb files (and optionally, the source files) again. And what platform you debug with? Does all the platforms not work?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I am debugging in android platform. Yes I am able to load the pdb symbols present in external code. But I don't know how to proceed from there. I want to debug the codes in external project like Base library and commons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed that by adding the following code in **Directory.Build.props** of **BaseLibrary**(Any library which we want to debug) and **restart your visual studio**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
    <SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Check the properties of the project file by navigating through **properties of each project you want to debug-> Build ->Advanced** and check if the debug information is **embedded**. **Rebuild** **BaseLibrary solution** and check **.snupkg files** are generated in base library's **Output** folder.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try debugging with dnspy (https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy)... it allows for debugging most .net projects even without having source code, because it decompiles on demand. You can attach to running process or start from dnspy debugger. Debug/windows/modules to find the dll's, double click on any one of them to view source code and set breakpoints

Comment: I'm only able to navigate to the assembly not the source code.

Comment: Double clicking on the assembly in the modules should make it show up in the left panel where you can drill down to the classes and functions ( the assembly explorer panel )

Comment: I tried double clicking on the DLL in module but it didn't open the source code anywhere. I have attached the screenshot in the question. Please look into it.

Comment: It looks you are using vs and not dnspy?

Comment: I ran the DLL in dnSpy and I was able to open the DLL. But I am not able to debug that. Also I want debug through my xamarin project.

Comment: What should be the executable for doing the debugging in dnSpy?

Comment: You have 2 options.. attach to an already running process or start exe using start debugging where you can specify the exe to start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232240/discussion-between-rekna-and-judson-abraham).